# What is the proof for this sum of sum generalized harmonic number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

I believe this sum: $$\sum_{m=2}^k\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(nm)^{-s}$$ to be equal to $$\frac 12((H_k^{s})^2-H_k^{(2s)})$$ where $H_k^{s}$ is the generalized harmonic number. I only discovered this by experimenting on Wolfram.com.  Can someone please show a proof of this?

Comment: The generalized harmonic number is $H_k^s = \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i^s}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proved straightforwardly by working backwards. Note that the desired sum can be rewritten as
$$ S \equiv \sum_{m=2}^k \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (nm)^{-s} = \sum_{1\le n<m\le k} (nm)^{-s} $$
Starting with
\begin{eqnarray}
(H_k^s)^2 &=& \left(\sum_{n=1}^k n^{-s}\right)^2 = \sum_{n,m=1}^k (nm)^{-s} \\
&=& \sum_{1\le n<m\le k} (nm)^{-s} + \sum_{1\le n=m \le k} (nm)^{-s} + \sum_{1\le m<n\le k} (nm)^{-s}  \\
&=& 2\sum_{1\le n<m\le k} (nm)^{-s} + \sum_{n=1}^k n^{-2s} \\
&=& 2S + H_k^{2s}
\end{eqnarray}
where we decomposed the sum over the region $(n,m)\in\{1,\ldots,k\}^2$ into three sums, and used the symmetry of $n\leftrightarrow m$ in the last sum. It's then clear that
$$S=\frac12 \left((H_k^s)^2-H_k^{2s}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks @Leo!  I assume this would work for any series of numbers, right?  Not just the natural numbers?  Say if i used the primes instead of the naturals and instead of the harmonic series, I would get the prime zeta function.  Would all of this still check out?

Comment: Yup, since this identity is true as long as your original sum can be written as $\sum_{n<m: (n,m)\in D^2} (nm)^{-s}$, irrespective of what the domain $D$ actually is (be it natural numbers or primes)

Comment: How would I go about finding formulae in terms of the harmonic number like this for similar expressions with more sums?  For example, how would I express $$\sum_{q=3}^k \sum_{m=2}^{q-1} \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (nmq)^{-s}$$ or $$\sum_{t=4}^k \sum_{q=3}^{t-1} \sum_{m=2}^{q-1} \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} (nmqt)^{-s}$$ in terms of harmonic numbers like we did with two sums?

Comment: @joriki maybe you could give me some advice about my comment above since you already probably know where I'm going with this.

Comment: BTW, I made another post specifically for this question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348409/how-do-i-calculate-these-sum-of-sum-expressions-in-terms-of-the-generalized-harm